# How to calculate transform matrix from rotate/translate/scale/skew

Tags: matrix

I have managed to put scale, translate and rotate into one matrix array, but I cant get skew inside it. Does anyone know how I can do that?

Thank you in advance and please excause my bad english.
Best regards.

```
//Skew
//var a = Math.PI/4;
//var matrix = [ 1,Math.tan(a),0, Math.tan(a),1,0, 0,0,1 ];

//rotate
//var r = (45) * Math.PI/180;



var matrix=[sx*Math.cos(r), -sx*Math.sin(r), (-cx*Math.cos(r)+cy*Math.sin(r)+cx)*sx+tx, sy*Math.sin(r), sy*Math.cos(r), (-cx*Math.sin(r)-cy*Math.cos(r)+cy)*sy+ty, 0, 0, 1];
```